# TypeScript: Log.info Doesn't print?

Tags: typescript, loginfo

`Log.info(window.btoa("Hello World!"));` Doesn't print?

I am running Log.info in a test.

```
var x = window.btoa("Hello World!");
Log.info("return:" + x);
```

I am currently doing a project that requires me to change the code from `base64` to `JSON` String, and I am just playing around with the codes.

More info: I am using WebStorm as the programming environment, and Webstorm doesn't entirely support TypeScript.  console.log wouldn't print in WebStorm, because its console only supports JavaScript.  But there's a function that allows the consumers to convert TypeScript into JavaScript, and only the Event Log can cope with TypeScript in WebStorm.

Edit: Just Saw an error when I put it in the front of the test: ReferenceError: Window is not defined. Weird enough - There's a Window library, with btoa with it. So how's Window's not defined?

Comment: There's nothing like Log in Javascript, at least natively.

Comment: It's TypeScript, mb

Comment: Log is the event log that allows us to debug/print out the codes.  I am using WebStorm so this might be only available in WebStorm I think

Comment: window.btoa is not available in all engines. Are you seeing an error when the code runs?

Comment: Used try-catch statement to test window.btoa. I didn't see any error.

Comment: Just Saw an error when I put it in the front of the test: ReferenceError: Window is not defined.  Weird enough - There's a Window library, with btoa with it.  So how's Window's not defined?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Log defined, but in Chrome, you can use **console.log**.
Press F12 in Chrome:

```
console.log(window.btoa("Hello World!"));
```

as shown below

[image]